# jQuery scroll to top freezing if called mid-scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have some code using jQuery's `scrollTop(0)` method which is not working correctly on Chrome (Version 56.0.2924.87).

My code sets a 2 second timeout which does the following:

- Scrolls to the top of the screen.
- Un-hides a div which has 100% width and height and requests the user to complete some action.
- Appends a class to the html tag which sets `overflow: hidden`.
- Once users completes the action it will remove the class and hide the div so they can continue scrolling.

This is working relibaly on Firefox.

On Chrome, if the 2 second timeout executes while the user is **not** scrolling, then it works as expected. However, if the 2 second timeout is called while the user is in the middle of scrolling, it seems to freeze.

I have created [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PgzaMOcNOknRy8QTFJ6v?p=info) containing all the code. The issue does not occur if you test within the in-line demo window, you need to click on the Preview in a Separate Window (blue button top right inside the code demo).

In my demo, this is what happens if the timeout runs while I am **not** actively scrolling:

[image]

And this is what happens if the timeout is executed while I am scrolling down (mid-scroll):
[image]

How can I make this work reliably on Chrome even if the user is currently scrolling on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you can not see the div when is display. When the event is called in the middle of the scrolling the scroll bar hidden and the div apper at the top of your page, but your viewport is not at the top position. If you set the div CSS position property to fixed it will work, [css position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). the fixed value of the position property is relative to the viewport.

So the problem is not on your jquery code.

```
code here
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IZsN9NpyiWzPdJ5dzdYH?p=info)

And check this:

- Scrolls to the top of the screen.
- Once users complete the action it will remove the class and hide the div so they can continue scrolling.

I think it will be best if they can continue at the position the wear before.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you add stop(). before the .scrollTop(0)?

```
$('html,body,document').stop().scrollTop(0);
```

I am not an expert, but may be worth a shot.

Hope it helps.